# css how to avoid fixed height in this code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I try to make some tabs. At the moment they are working without javascript, but if you have a solution for my problem with js, it is also okay.

Problem: I have a fixed height for my content, which leads to an overflowing text if the text is larger then the container height.
How can I avoid the fixed height and having my content always as heigh as its text?

Demo:

```css
body {
background: grey;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
}

.tab label {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
}

.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-2" checked>
    <label for="tab-4">Tab One</label>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas
        semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum,
        eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam
        dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec
        eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum,
        elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros
        eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies
        eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae,
        ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque
        egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-2">
    <label for="tab-5">Tab Two</label>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>

      <img src="http://placebear.com/200/100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-6" name="tab-group-2">
    <label for="tab-6">Tab Three</label>

    <div class="content">
      You made it this far?!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I avoid the fixed height and having my content always as heigh as its text?

EDIT:

Now when adding some text after the tabs, the hole tabs are in front of the text. How can I have it that the text is under the tabs? see: jsfiddle.net/BennyAlex/trxz43mf/6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should remove `bottom:0`; from `.content` and use `display:block` instead of 
`z-index` to change tabs

```css
body {
  background: grey;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
}

.tab label {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
}

.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 27px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display:none;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-2" checked>
    <label for="tab-4">Tab One</label>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas
        semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum,
        eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam
        dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec
        eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum,
        elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros
        eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies
        eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae,
        ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque
        egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-2">
    <label for="tab-5">Tab Two</label>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>

      <img src="http://placebear.com/200/100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-6" name="tab-group-2">
    <label for="tab-6">Tab Three</label>

    <div class="content">
      You made it this far?!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey can you help me again, please? Now when adding some text after the  tabs, the hole tabs are in front of the text. How can I have it that the text is under the tabs? see:https://jsfiddle.net/BennyAlex/trxz43mf/6/

Comment: you are using absolute position on the .content element... which makes @BennyAlex it don't take any space on the page ... if you want to add stuff under the tab element you have two choices .. 1-fix the height of content and add margin-top equal to content's height to the element bellow ...or you need to change the tab structure by using JavaScript https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: isnt there any other way? Both ways are really bad ... :/

Comment: not that i know of ... it looks like you don't wanna use javascript

Comment: I already use javascript but I use Ember and there are the tabs will be create by a generator, and then the result is: tablabel&tab-content, tablabel&tabcontent, ... and on your example from w3 there are all tablabels at the top

Comment: then you can easily achieve it using javascript

Comment: okay, but how I archive the same style like in the demo here?

Answer (score 0):

You make your div to be of type: - display: inline-block

Comment: which div do you mean? I couldnt figured it out

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

`overflow:auto;` to your `.content`

```css
body {
background: grey;
}

.tabs {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;
  /* This part sucks */
  clear: both;
  margin: 25px 0;
}

.tab {
  float: left;
}

.tab label {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  left: 1px;
}

.tab [type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 28px;
  left: 0;
  overflow:auto;
  background: white;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label {
  background: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  z-index: 2;
}

[type=radio]:checked ~ label ~ .content {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-4" name="tab-group-2" checked>
    <label for="tab-4">Tab One</label>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
        Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis
        tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan
        porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas
        semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum,
        eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam
        dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec
        eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum,
        elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros
        eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies
        eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae,
        ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque
        egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-5" name="tab-group-2">
    <label for="tab-5">Tab Two</label>

    <div class="content">
      <p>Stuff for Tab Two</p>

      <img src="http://placebear.com/200/100">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tab">
    <input type="radio" id="tab-6" name="tab-group-2">
    <label for="tab-6">Tab Three</label>

    <div class="content">
      You made it this far?!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but then you have to scroll. The content div should be as larg as its text, if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

this will automatically adjust depents on your screen size
use vw or em instead of px for ex:

```
style="height:100em" or style="height:100vw"
```

Comment: I want it to be as high as its content, not as heigh as my hole display